# Spring StateMachine reusable statemachine instance

Tags: java, spring, state-machine, spring-statemachine

I have spring state machine like in the image below:

[image]

I want the state machine to be started at the start of the app. And after that it should go in the Re-State where on some time (Scheduled) it go in State GetOrders with SubStates (GetA, GetB and GetC). After that if there is some error it should go in the error, otherwise if everything is okay it should go in the Re-State where it should wait for the Scheduler.

This is my config

```
@Override
    public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<States, Events> config) throws Exception {
        config.withConfiguration()
          .autoStartup(true)
          .machineId("orderMachine");
    }
```

And this is the method for the scheduler:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 1 * *")
    public void startStateMachine() {
        
        StateMachine<States, Events> sm = factory.getStateMachine();
        sm.start();
        sm.sendEvent(Events.ReState);
    }
```

Everything is working okay but I have noticed that every time this method executes, the stateMachine that is starting have different UUID with the previous one but the Id is same. So I think I am making multiple instances of the state machine. Is it possible to reuse the same state machine or not finishing the process. Because in my case most of the time the state of the machine should be in Re-State. It can be considered as waiting state.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [SpringStateMachineService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/api/org/springframework/statemachine/service/StateMachineService.html) to get a state machine instance instead of explicitly retrieving it from StateMachineFactory. You can use [default](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/api/org/springframework/statemachine/service/DefaultStateMachineService.html) implementation provided by Spring:

```
@Bean
public StateMachineService<State, Event> stateMachineService(
        final StateMachineFactory<State, Event> stateMachineFactory) {
    return new DefaultStateMachineService<>(stateMachineFactory);
}
```

So, your code will look like:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 1 * *")
public void startStateMachine() {
    // here we need to get stateMachineId from some storage
    stateMachineService.acquireStateMachine(stateMachineId, true)
            .sendEvent(Events.ReState);
}
```

In the code above you need to provide particular state machine ids. Usually, I store them in the database, query them and instantiate state machine for each one.
Persisting state machine context is out of scope of the question. See [Persisting State Machine](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/#sm-persist)

Answer (score -1):

Well your state machine should be most likely public and static. So that you would make sure by that there is only one instance of your machine.

Comment: I have changed the creating of the StateMachine to be static and public and still the UUID is different :)

Comment: I think you should provide a little bit more of a code to actually play around and to be able to test it.

Comment: What you mean by providing more code? State and Events enums, transitions config, state config, actions? I think that any of that wont help... Its just a basic config